# How can I set a Team folder to be accessible by ALL Team members?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace-for-business, google-drive-sharing, google-shared-drive

I only see the option to Manage members and select which ones.

I just want to give the whole team (company) access.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a group
2. Add all the organization users to that group
3. Add the group as a member of the corresponding Team Drive

References

- [Add all users to a group](https://support.google.com/a/answer/66338?hl=en)
- [Share files with Team Drives](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7286514?hl=en)
- [Manage your Team Drive users and activity](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7337635?hl=en)

Comment: When you create a new group, what is supposed to go in "group email"? Why is this needed?

Comment: On group email you write the "username" to be used for the group email address that you want to use. That username should be unique for the domain.

Comment: @Rubén In the Member access -> Add Members dialog of my Team Drives I can only specify people, google groups aren't accepted (either using their name or email address). Am I missing something?

Comment: @Miguel please post a new question including the message that is showing when you try to add the group and if that group is a consumer group, a group from your domain or from another domain.